# Function that check if letters and or whole word is a contained in a given string

Tags: php, regex

I want to solve the following problem through regular expression

1. All 5 letters 'g', 'o', 'l', 'd','e','n' are included (in any
   sequence) and
2. The string 'golden' is a substring of the given string.

If 1 holds (but 2 does not), return 1.
If both 1 and 2 hold, return 2.
Otherwise return 0.

here is my code.

```
function checkstrling($input, $substring) 
{
    $voodoo = preg_match("(".implode("(.*?)",array_map('preg_quote',str_split($substring))).")",$input,$matches);
    if( !$voodoo) return 0; // no match
    $pieces = implode("",array_slice($matches,1)); // in-between bits
    if( $pieces !=="") return 1; // there was stuff in between
    return 2; // substring found without interruption
}

var_dump(checkstrling("xgolensssx","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("abcgxyommlgdqqesn","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("xgoldensssx","golden"));
```

The function work find when i call and provide the following parameter it work fine.

```
var_dump(checkstrling("xgolensssx","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("abcgxyommlgdqqesn","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("xgoldensssx","golden"));
```

But does not work properly when i call the function again with the following paramenter.

```
var_dump(checkstrling("somegxoxdxlxnmme","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("somegxoxlxdxemnmgoldenv","golden"));
```

Answer (score 3):

### Brief

No need for regex here, it'll just complicate things.

---

### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/5812dS)

```
function checkstrling($input, $substring) 
{
    if (strpos($input, $substring) !== false) {
       return 2;
    }
    foreach (str_split($substring) as $char) {
        if (strpos($input, $char) === false) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

print checkstrling("xgolensssx","golden");              // 0
print checkstrling("abcgxyommlgdqqesn","golden");       // 1
print checkstrling("xgoldensssx","golden");             // 2

print checkstrling("somegxoxdxlxnmme","golden");        // 1
print checkstrling("somegxoxlxdxemnmgoldenv","golden"); // 2
```

**Sidenote**: You can change `str_split($substring)` to `array_unique(str_split($substring))` to remove duplicates before going through the loop. This may improve performance for larger `$substring`s that contain duplicate letters (such as the word `goldenrod`: `goldenr` would be the resulting array).

---

### Explanation

- If word exists in string, return `2`, otherwise, continue
- Loop over each character in `$substring`

  - If the character is not found, return `0`
- This point is only reached if the loop was completed successfully, return `1`

Comment: @salathe thanks for the edit, I definitely overlooked that section.

Comment: Honestly, haven't thought of that (+1).

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple lookaheads:

```
(?=[^g]*g)
(?=[^o]*o)
(?=[^l]*l)
(?=[^d]*d)
(?=[^e]*e)
(?=[^n]*n)
```

The pattern is always the same: look for anything **not** `g` zero or more times, than look for `g`.

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

function checkstrling($input, $substring) {
    $regex = '~(?=[^g]*g)(?=[^o]*o)(?=[^l]*l)(?=[^d]*d)(?=[^e]*e)(?=[^n]*n).+~';

    if ((preg_match($regex, $input) && (strpos($input, $substring) !== false))) {
        return 2;
    } else if (preg_match($regex, $input)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

var_dump(checkstrling("xgolensssx","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("abcgxyommlgdqqesn","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("xgoldensssx","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("somegxoxdxlxnmme","golden"));
var_dump(checkstrling("somegxoxlxdxemnmgoldenv","golden"));
?>
```

Which yields

```
int(0)
int(1)
int(2)
int(1)
int(2)
```